# Getting page.evaluate not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, node-modules, puppeteer

I created a helper to manage my code in my other module. I wrote this piece of code:

```
 Scraper: async function(page, selector1, selector2, selector3) {
        let list_of_items = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let items = [];
            let elemend = selector1

            let items_present = document.querySelectorAll(elemend);

            items_present.forEach((element) => {
                let itemJson = {};
                try {
                    itemJson.name = element.querySelector(selector2).innerText;

                    if(element.querySelector(selector3)){
                        itemJson.price = element.querySelector(selector3).innerText;
                    }
                }
                catch (exception){

                }
                items.push(itemJson);
            });
            return items;
        });
        console.dir(list_of_items);
```

Every time I try to execute my code it fails and says evaluate is not a function

```
await Scraper.Scraper(hunt.div_container, hunt.name_selector, hunt.price_selector);
```

Comment: You're passing three arguments to `Scraper.Scraper()` instead of four, so it tries to execute `hunt.div_container.evaluate` which is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it wrong, do not do call it as `await Scraper.Scraper()` call it like a normal function `Scraper.Scraper()` also maybe don't use the same name for the class and function as that can get confusing and will become a nightmare to debug in a not so distant time and lastly ensure that the class as been instantiated first, cause it seems to me that your automation tool is inside a class, so ensure you instantiate it first before calling functions inside of it